# Laurent series and residue.

Tags: laurent-series

Why is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/w)^{2n+1} = \sum_{m=-\infty}^0 w^{2m+1}$, using the identity ($m=-n$)? Why shouldn't the exponent be equal to $2m-1$?
Also, why is the following correct - $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/n!)(1/z)^n = \sum_{m=-\infty}^0 z^{-m}/(-m)!$? Why shouldn't the exponent of $z$ be equal to $m$? And last, why is the $a_{-1}$ term of this Laurent series (i.e. the residue) equal to $1$ at $z = 0$?

Comment: You can see directly from the definition of notation $\Sigma$. The residue at $z=0$ is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't quite understand how the above equalities for the sums hold. Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the exponent is $2m-1$ and not $2m+1$. Respect to the other question it is evident that the exponent of $z$ is $m$, otherwise the equality only holds for $z=0$.
In this case the Laurent series at $z=0$ is 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{z^n}=a_{0}+\frac{a_1}{z}+\frac{a_2}{z^2}+\cdots$$
where the term $a_1$ is the residue by definition, which in this case is 1.

Comment: Okay, great. Now, one final concern regarding this topic - suppose I have the following series: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(l+n+1)/2}z^l}{((l+n+1)/2)!}$. Why is $a_{-1}$ for an odd $n$ equal to zero?

Comment: Also, doesn't $a_{-1}$ imply $l=-1$?

Comment: Are you sure that the exponent of $z$ is $l$ instead of $n$?

Comment: Pardon me, it should have been $\sum_{l=-n-1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(l+n+1)/2}z^l}{((l+n+1)/2)!}$.

Comment: Now, wouldn't $a_{-1}$ imply $l = -1$? And, why would the former be equal to zero for odd $n$?

Comment: Nope, that's how it is written in my text.

Comment: But why would $a_{-1}$ be zero? I realise that if $n$ were odd then $(n/2)!$ has no sense, but is that the only reason why $a_{-1}$ is zero?

Comment: well, there is something wrong with that series. For instance, as you can see the denominator is a factorial, so $\frac{l+n+1}{2}$ must be integer (because the factorial only is defined for integers). Then if $l$ is the index, it cannot take all the positive integer values.

Comment: The original question was to find the Laurent series for: $$\frac{e^{-z^2}}{z^{n+1}}$$ Does it make more sense now? In other words, do you reckon you could please clarify why $a_{-1}$ would be zero for odd $n$?

Comment: The expansion of $e^{-z^2}$ is $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{l}z^{2l}}{l!}$. Then 
the expansion of $\dfrac{e^{-z^2}}{z^{n+1}}$ is $$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{l}z^{2l-n-1}}{l!}$$
where $2l-n-1=-1$ iff $n=2l$.  Thus, for $n$ odd $z^{-1}$ is not present in the expansion. Therefore $a_1=0$.

Comment: First, doesn't the exponent of a Laurent series have to be a single letter, such as m,n,l etc.? I.e. isn't a change of index requisite here in order to correctly formulate the answer as a Laurent series? Furthermore, were I interested in finding $a_{-1}$ for another series but at z=3 (and not at z=0) let's say. How would that affect the methodology we just delineated, viz. merely finding the coefficient of $z^{-1}$?

Comment: You are right, a Laurent series has an only one index, which in this case is $l$. You have to realize that $n$ is just a constant. A change of index is not mandatory here. Why should it be? The residue of a Laurent series at $z=a$ is by definition the coefficient of the term $\dfrac{1}{z-a}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/w)^{2n+1} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty w^{-2n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=\infty}^0 w^{-2n-1}\\
&=\sum_{-m=\infty}^0 w^{-2n-1}\\
&=\sum_{m=-\infty}^0 w^{2m+1}\\
\end{align}

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. Why would the exponent be $2m+1$ and not $2m-1$??